# For multiple pages use single requireJs config or multiple?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a rather large multi-page website. Each page will require a set of common js libraries (jquery, etc) as well as at least one js file specific to that page (that sets up an js functionality specific to said page).

I can have one config file for the entire site that sets up all my paths. This seems like the logical choice so that a config file for the paths  needed for a specific file will not be needed for each page (a pain to maintain, and essentially negates what I am trying to do with requirejs).

However, part of me cringes at the idea of having paths available to a page that  will never need them.

Question: What is recommended approach: use one combined `require.config` or multiple smaller configs (common + one-per-page)?

Note: I will be pulling js files from a CDN so none of the paths will be local, which I know isn't really a concern with the config file.

Answer (score 6):

Generally I'd advise bundling your paths together, not only does this tend to be a convention other developers will expect. It also means your options can be re-used by the build tool by simply [pointing it to file containing your config options](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L35).

However, if you really would like to separate the options then multiple calls to `require.config()` are permitted and the config object will simply be mixed.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'moduleA': 'bla/bla'
    }
})

require.config({
    paths: {
        'moduleB': 'bla/bla2'
    }
})
```